# access outside data from within callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am having problems accessing *nodes[i]* from the callback function inside 
*chrome.bookmarks.create*. Any idea guys ? I am thinking this is because of closure. Any way to make it work ?

```
function copyBookmarks(nodes,folderId){            

    for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){

        var properties={
            parentId:folderId,
            index:nodes[i].index,
            title:nodes[i].title,
            url:nodes[i].url
        };   

        chrome.bookmarks.create(properties,function(newNode){              

          console.log(nodes[i]);//this doesnt work

        });                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is accessing `nodes` just fine, but the problem is that `i` will be the value after the loop completes. The usual solution is to make a copy of `i` in each iteration through a self-executing function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

    // Other code...

    // Self executing function to copy i as a local argument
    (function (i) {
        chrome.bookmarks.create(properties, function (newNode) {
            console.log(nodes[i]);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: The same way you can pass the node: `(function(node){…})(nodes[i])`

Comment: @Denis in fact, that's even better, in case the order of the `nodes` array changes.

Comment: @anp because you are calling the anonymous function. Just like you call a regular function with: `someFunction(i)`, you call the anonymous function by putting `()` after it, with whatever arguments you want to pass in.